# Is there a way to end a recursive method when a certain condition is met in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, break

Is there a way to abruptly return to the method that calls the method below when the condition is met? Something similar to a break for loops.

```
public void createTree(TreeNode tree) throws IOException {
    if (i >= preorder.length) {
        // Leave recursive method
    } else if (preorder[i] == '0') {
        tree.value = '0';
        tree.left = tree.right = null;
        i++;                
    } else {
        tree.value = preorder[i];
        i++;
        tree.left = new TreeNode();
        createTree(tree.left);
        tree.right = new TreeNode();
        createTree(tree.right);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to abort anywhere in your recursion? (i.e tree.right == null)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "abruptly end"? End the *current part* of the recursion and let the rest continue? Or end the *entire* recursive call and step back to the non-recursive part of your code?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Is there a way to make the method return without executing the remaining recursions?

Comment: Just to be clear: if this condition is `true`, then it's some kind of error condition and the *entire* recursive call can be considered "wrong" or "unnecessary" in some way. Is that right?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: It's not exactly an error, but it's the condition to check when all the preorder[i] elements have been passed through and no more recursions are needed if that makes sense. I'm not very good with programming lingo yet, so my explanation might be bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return a status from the method :

```
/**
 * @return false if the recursion has been aborted
 */
public boolean createTree(TreeNode tree) throws IOException {
    if (i >= preorder.length) {
        return false;
    } 
    else if (preorder[i] == '0') {
        tree.value = '0';
        tree.left = tree.right = null;
        i++;                
    } 
    else {
        tree.value = preorder[i];
        i++;
        tree.left = new TreeNode();
        if (!createTree(tree.left)) {
            return false;
        };
        tree.right = new TreeNode();
        if (!createTree(tree.right)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually unintentionally solved another problem in my code as well. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can simply let the method return. Then the recursion will go backwards and the remaining statements will be executed.

Comment: +1 the general principle of recursion is that the recusive method returns the value of the basic case at some point.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without executing the remaining statements?

Comment: If the `return` is in its own little `if` block, there shouldn't be any remaining statements.

Answer (score 0):

you could throw an exception, but this seems to be "dirty"

Comment: Never, ever use exceptions for logic flow.  Ever.  An exception can be thrown if something exceptional has happened.  But solely for the purpose of terminating logic execution, never.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using an runtimeexception but i do not think it is a good design.

If my recursion went that far it means that it was required... and i will probably used a return