# How to stop recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, passwords, brute-force

I am carrying out a school project (java classes). The aim is to study and create some brute force password cracker algorithms (when i don't know the length of the password, so i try all passwords up to x characters) and compare how fast they work. Thanks to your advice I have been able to create this algorithm which looks more arranged than previous ones. However, i came across one problem with **recursion**

```
 if (keepworking) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                possibleCombinations(i, CHOICES, "");
            }
        }
.....
public static void possibleCombinations(int maxLength, char[] list, String curr) {
    if (curr.length() == maxLength) {
        tries++;
        if (curr.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println(curr);
            keepworking = false;
            return;
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            String oldCurr = curr;
            curr = curr + CHOICES[i];
            possibleCombinations(maxLength, CHOICES, curr);
            curr = oldCurr;
        }
    }
}
```

It works well, it finds the password, **but the program continues**.It always tries **all the possible combinations** (Number of tries is always **1178420165**) EVEN if the password have only 1 character. I am trying **to stop the recursion after it finds the password**, however i was not successful. I need the program to be **as fast as possible**

Could you give me advice why it doesnt stop and how to do it properly?

Comment: Are you sure this compiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as breaking out of loop is concerned, I would just put a condition to check for `keepworking` flag, e.g.:

```
public static void possibleCombinations(int maxLength, char[] list, String curr) {
    if(!keepworking){
      return;
    }
    if (curr.length() == maxLength) {
        tries++;
        if (curr.equals(password)) {
            System.out.println(curr);
            keepworking = false;
            return;
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            String oldCurr = curr;
            curr = curr + CHOICES[i];
            possibleCombinations(maxLength, CHOICES, curr);
            curr = oldCurr;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, regarding doing it properly, we should return a flag or something rather depending on global variable. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912257/is-there-a-way-to-end-a-recursive-method-when-a-certain-condition-is-met-in-java) SO answer for detailed explanation.

Comment: It would be better to return a boolean, and check the return value in the for loop, returning immediately if it is (say) true. Having mutable static state can be problematic.

Comment: How does this check with you on the stack?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are trying to use a while loop since recursion does its own looping. I wrote some pseudocode to help give you an idea of what you might be trying to do. This looks like a homework assignment so I'll leave the hard coding for you.

```
maxLength, password, curr

possibleCombinations(int maxLength, password, String curr) 
{
    if (curr.length == maxLength && curr != password)// The only other thing I would do with this condition is to make it also check if you used all the possible chars available. I'll leave that to you.
    {
        //Print message for password not found
    }
    else if (curr == password)
    {
        //print the found password
    }
    else
    {
        // brute force by changing the last char by one and 
        // if it is at the end of the char value limit, 
        // increase the first char by one and apply this same rule until
        // all of the char's values are maxed and add a new char to the end of the string.
        then,
        possibleCombinations(maxLength,password,curr)
    }
}
```

The point of recursion is to run through the same routine until you find a condition that ends the routine. You don't necessarily need to use a boolean to crack the password since the exit condition will be when you have a match.